# Wester Digital Passport External Hardisk failure

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I dropped my WD passport from a height of about 3 feet on a solid surface. I connected the harddisk to my Lapotop running windows 8.1. The LED on the haddisk is blinking. I can feel the hard disk spinning normally. The status bar shows my hardsik is connected.

Status bar showing the harddisk:

[image]

But the hardisk is not listed in my computer. Since it is a passport, I have to run the WD unlocker everytime to unlock the device. When I tried to open it, I/O error is shown.

I/O error:

[image]

What could be the possible fix for this problem? Are these sign of hard disk failure?

EDIT 1: Now I am hearing tickling sound.

Comment: You've just answered your own question. The biggest problem you have, however, is that you have encrypted the disk so if you took the disk to a recovery specialist there is almost zero chance of them recovering your data. Portable HDDs are useful but should never be taken for granted as a sole storage of backup data.

Comment: So, the failure is in the hard disk.? Instead of trying to recover it, is it possible to repair it by giving it to any service centre?

Comment: You could try to obtain an identical disk main board (it must be absolutely identical) and see if the error is simply a broken board. If the errors persist then the problem is physical and you will probably end up spending huge amounts of money for a data recovery specialist to remove the disk platters and attempt to recover your data using their tools. Your disk platter data is encrypted though, so they won't be able to recover individual files. It's all or nothing. A "service centre" repair will not do very much because a hard disk is specialist and requires careful handling and equipment.

Comment: P.s. a "ticking" sound is mechanical damage. Not good. Personally I would learn from the mistake and have a better backup strategy in future that covers such an eventuality as dropping a disk. Hint: cloud storage.